# Chrome onBeforeSendHeaders not catching FTP request

Tags: google-chrome-extension, ftp

I'm developing a chrome extension which will add **Authorization headers** to the requests.

For this I used **onBeforeSendHeaders**, but unfortunately it isn't working for **FTP** requests. I have given the permission in manifest and also in background

Manifest permissions says:

```
 "permissions": [
    "webRequest",
    "webRequestBlocking",
    "webNavigation",
    "tabs",
    "cookies",
    "ftp://*/*",
    "*://*/*"
  ]
```

and I used **onBeforeSendHeaders** like this:

```
chrome.webRequest.onBeforeSendHeaders.addListener(
      function(details) {
        if(details.url == "my_url"){       
               details.requestHeaders.push({'name':'Authorization','value':'my_value'});
                    return { requestHeaders: details.requestHeaders };
         }        
       },
    {urls: ['<all_urls>','ftp://*/*']},
    [ 'blocking', 'requestHeaders']
    );
 callback(true);
}
```

And also if I fail to open FTP in Chrome; is there any other way, where I could open FTP in terminal or putty using a single command (something like `ssh user@host -pw pass`)?

Comment: There are no headers in FTP. So it makes sense that the `onBeforeSendHeaders` is not triggered. And for the same reason, it does make sense trying to add "Authorization headers" to "FTP request".

Comment: ohh. thanks a lot @Martin ...can you suggest me a solution to open FTP server.. how should do it then.. is there something called credentials.. because when we click to open ftp server..it asks for credentials

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Comment: sorry but I din't got it.. where did I addressed volunteers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**onAuthRequired** is the solution to it, and worked for me:

```
var target = "ftp://ftpurl/";

var myCredentials = {
  username: "username",
  password: "pass"
};

var pendingRequests = [];

// A request has completed.
// We can stop worrying about it.
function completed(requestDetails) {
  console.log("completed: " + requestDetails.requestId);
  var index = pendingRequests.indexOf(requestDetails.requestId);
  if (index > -1) {
    pendingRequests.splice(index, 1);
  }
}

function provideCredentialsSync(requestDetails) {

  // If we have seen this request before, then
  // assume our credentials were bad, and give up.
  if (pendingRequests.indexOf(requestDetails.requestId) != -1) {
    console.log("bad credentials for: " + requestDetails.requestId);
    return {cancel:true};
  }
  pendingRequests.push(requestDetails.requestId);
  console.log("providing credentials for: " + requestDetails.requestId);
  return {authCredentials: myCredentials};
}

chrome.webRequest.onAuthRequired.addListener(
    provideCredentialsSync,
    {urls: [target]},
    ["blocking"]
  );

chrome.webRequest.onCompleted.addListener(
  completed,
  {urls: [target]}
);

chrome.webRequest.onErrorOccurred.addListener(
  completed,
  {urls: [target]}
);              

}
```